# how to angular-fullstack generator with angular 4

Tags: angular, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have installed yeoman generator angular-fullstack- generator. but, I need front end should have framework with angular 4. Where can I find the generator for that. am new to yeoman, so not much sure on generators.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Start-Angular:

https://github.com/seesharprun/generator-start-angular#readme

Basically, the commands are:

```
npm install --global yo generator-start-angular

yo start-angular

// yo start-angular --bootstrap
```

But maybe, there aren't a lot of new Yeoman Angular generator because they are no longer necessary...

Angular-cli provides the functionality of create and initialize a new Angular project. As simple as:

```
ng new my-new-project
```

Take a look at [Angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for generators here: http://yeoman.io/generators/

Comment: yes.I did that. but I do not find the required generator.